# parsing JSON - How do I grab data within multiple entries in JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, api

I have a little app that pulls data from several API's.  In all of my cases so far I get JSON back for a single response, but for this one I get an array of hits.  How do I access the data in the array??  Here's the basic structure of my javascript grabbing data from the returned JSON:

```
// pull article from JSON
function getArticle(article) {
  document.getElementById('articletitle').innerHTML = (article.title);
  ...
};
```

So that works great for a single response, it grabs the article title and throws it in a div.  But what if I get back an array of articles like this

JSON:

```
getArticle({"Title":"title","Rights":"Copyright (C)",...[{"ResultId":1,"DocType":"ar","DocTitle":"some title",...
```

My main question is just how to grab say the `DocTitle` here of a given article?  simply grabbing `.DocTitle` doesn't seem to get through.  BONUS POINTS for modifying the javascript to iterate through the array of articles returned too.

Thanks a million.

Comment: You don't need to have = (article.title); it should just be = article.title;  It would also be helpful if you provided a full example of JSON that you are using the ... is confusing me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your question this:

```
getArticle({"Title":"title","Rights":"Copyright (C)",...
[{"ResultId":1,"DocType":"ar","DocTitle":"some title",...
```

Has been over-abbreviated to the point that we have to guess what you meant. You can't have an array sitting in the middle of an object unless it is associated with a key. You need something like this:

```
getArticle({"Title":"title","Rights":"Copyright (C)",...
    "articles" : [{"ResultId":1,"DocType":"ar","DocTitle":"some title",...]
});

function getArticle(article) {
   alert(article.articles[0].DocTitle); // first item in array: "some title"

   for (var i = 0; i < article.articles.length; i++) {
      var currentArticle = article.articles[i];
      alert(currentArticle.ResultId + ": " + currentArticle.DocTitle);
   }
}
```

Note I've added the key "articles" within your object.

Or you can return an array on its own instead of as part of another object:

```
getArticle([{"ResultId":1,"DocType":"ar","DocTitle":"some title",...},{"ResultId":2,...},...]);

function getArticle(articles) {
   for (var i = 0; i < articles.length; i++)
      alert(articles[i].DocTitle);
}
```

Comment: Hey sorry, I basically bailed on this part of the project cause the API i was using turned out to be kind of dumb.  But this answer was very helpful in general.  The key was using the 'key'.  no pun intended.  Thanks much.

Comment: Along with your answer this helped me understand the structure on a more basic level which helped: http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/get_started_with_json/.

Answer (score 0):

[{"ResultId":1,"DocType":"ar","DocTitle":"some title"},{"ResultId":2,"DocType":"ar","DocTitle":"some title"}]
This array should have an index too.

```
var test={"Title":"title",content:[{"ResultId":1,"DocType":"ar","DocTitle":"some title"},{"ResultId":2,"DocType":"ar","DocTitle":"some title"}]};
alert(test.content[0].DocTitle);
```